# LinkageError when using MethodHandle.publicLookup() in WAR files

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, linkageerror, methodhandle

we have a problem that we can not explain why it happens. perhaps someone here can us give some hints whats going on in this case.

we have tis simple reproucer written that shows the problem

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner runner() {
        return (args) -> {
            final Class<?> refc = Class.forName("com.example.demo.Family$Child");
            System.out.println(refc.getClassLoader());
            MethodHandle handle1 = MethodHandles.lookup().findStatic(refc, "getFirstChild", MethodType.methodType(refc));
            System.out.println("handle1 = " + handle1);
            MethodHandle handle2 = MethodHandles.publicLookup().findStatic(refc, "getFirstChild", MethodType.methodType(refc));
            System.out.println("handle2 = " + handle2);
        };
    }
}

class Family {
    public enum Child {
        TOM, PAUL;

        public static Child getFirstChild() {
            return TOM;
        }
    }
}
```

when we now build a war file and depoly it to the tomcat everything is fine, **but** when we deploy it a second time with a different context path it crashes with the following exception

```
09-Jun-2017 09:21:54.706 SCHWERWIEGEND [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/demo2]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1483)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:200)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: no such method: com.example.demo.Family$Child.getFirstChild()Child/invokeStatic
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName.makeAccessException(MemberName.java:867)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1003)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.resolveOrFail(MethodHandles.java:1386)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findStatic(MethodHandles.java:780)
    at com.example.demo.Application.lambda$runner$0(Application.java:32)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.example.demo.Family$Child.getFirstChild()Lcom/example/demo/Family$Child;" the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) of the current class, java/lang/Object, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/ParallelWebappClassLoader) for the method's defining class, com/example/demo/Family$Child, have different Class objects for the type com/example/demo/Family$Child used in the signature
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolve(MemberName.java:975)
    at java.lang.invoke.MemberName$Factory.resolveOrFail(MemberName.java:1000)
    ... 61 more
```

the only thing we found is that the cause is the publicLookup(). looking at the javadoc mentions some issues when using publicLookup() we we do not fully understand it.

Comment: I've also seen the problem that creating a methodhandle (for LambdaMetafactory in my case) fails the second time creates. For me it was in plain old java, with a class from another classloader, and the same LinkageError. FWIW, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441650/lambdametafactory-to-access-class-on-a-different-classloader).