# Newly generated linkki project using archetype throws Exception

Tags: linkki

I create a new linkki-Spring-Projekt as described here (https://linkki-framework.org/tutorial/02_project_setup/index.html), but it is not running. I get an org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'de.ts.ns.tg.Test.view.TestView': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [de.ts.ns.tg.Test.view.TestView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.linkki.core.binding.LinkkiBindingException: Error while updating UI (Cannot read value from object: de.ts.ns.tg.Test.view.HelloPmo@61527686, property: name in org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.ReadMethod.readValueWithExceptionHandling(ReadMethod.java:75)) in Binding: org.linkki.core.ui.wrapper.FormItemComponentWrapper@2e80be44 <=> BehaviorDependentDispatcher[HelloPmo#name]
    -> StaticValueDispatcher[HelloPmo#name]
    -> ReflectionPropertyDispatcher[HelloPmo#name]
    -> ExceptionPropertyDispatcher[HelloPmo#name]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:332) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator.getOrCreate(SpringInstantiator.java:117) ~[vaadin-spring-23.1.3.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.di.Instantiator.createRouteTarget(Instantiator.java:193) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.lambda$getRouteTarget$1(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:130) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.getRouteTarget(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:129) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.sendBeforeEnterEventAndPopulateChain(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:483) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.createChainIfEmptyAndExecuteBeforeEnterNavigation(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:464) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.handle(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:202) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.handle(JavaScriptNavigationStateRenderer.java:78) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.handleNavigation(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:317) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.renderViewForRoute(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:280) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.JavaScriptBootstrapUI.connectClient(JavaScriptBootstrapUI.java:147) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.invokeMethod(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:222) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.invokeMethod(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:199) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.invokeMethod(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:149) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.handleNode(PublishedServerEventHandlerRpcHandler.java:132) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:75) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:438) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:419) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:419) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:320) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:115) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1564) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:299) ~[flow-server-23.1.3.jar:23.1.3]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:109) ~[vaadin-spring-23.1.3.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:353) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [de.ts.ns.tg.Test.view.TestView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.linkki.core.binding.LinkkiBindingException: Error while updating UI (Cannot read value from object: de.ts.ns.tg.Test.view.HelloPmo@61527686, property: name in org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.ReadMethod.readValueWithExceptionHandling(ReadMethod.java:75)) in Binding: org.linkki.core.ui.wrapper.FormItemComponentWrapper@2e80be44 <=> BehaviorDependentDispatcher[HelloPmo#name]
    -> StaticValueDispatcher[HelloPmo#name]
    -> ReflectionPropertyDispatcher[HelloPmo#name]
    -> ExceptionPropertyDispatcher[HelloPmo#name]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:224) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 85 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.linkki.core.binding.LinkkiBindingException: Error while updating UI (Cannot read value from object: de.ts.ns.tg.Test.view.HelloPmo@61527686, property: name in org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.ReadMethod.readValueWithExceptionHandling(ReadMethod.java:75)) in Binding: org.linkki.core.ui.wrapper.FormItemComponentWrapper@2e80be44 <=> BehaviorDependentDispatcher[HelloPmo#name]
    -> StaticValueDispatcher[HelloPmo#name]
    -> ReflectionPropertyDispatcher[HelloPmo#name]
    -> ExceptionPropertyDispatcher[HelloPmo#name]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.ElementBinding.updateFromPmo(ElementBinding.java:84) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.BindingContext.add(BindingContext.java:186) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.BindingContext.bind(BindingContext.java:405) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.uicreation.UiCreator.lambda$createComponent$2(UiCreator.java:261) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.util.Optionals.ifPresentOrElse(Optionals.java:44) ~[linkki-utils-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.uicreation.UiCreator.createComponent(UiCreator.java:254) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.uicreation.UiCreator.createUiElement(UiCreator.java:124) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.ui.creation.section.SectionLayoutDefinition.addSectionComponent(SectionLayoutDefinition.java:133) ~[linkki-core-vaadin23-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.ui.creation.section.SectionLayoutDefinition.lambda$createSectionContent$5(SectionLayoutDefinition.java:129) ~[linkki-core-vaadin23-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:395) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at org.linkki.core.ui.creation.section.SectionLayoutDefinition.createSectionContent(SectionLayoutDefinition.java:129) ~[linkki-core-vaadin23-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.ui.creation.section.SectionLayoutDefinition.createChildren(SectionLayoutDefinition.java:93) ~[linkki-core-vaadin23-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.uicreation.UiCreator.lambda$createComponent$1(UiCreator.java:259) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.util.Optionals.ifPresentOrElse(Optionals.java:42) ~[linkki-utils-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.uicreation.UiCreator.createComponent(UiCreator.java:254) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.uicreation.UiCreator.createComponent(UiCreator.java:212) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.uicreation.UiCreator.createComponent(UiCreator.java:178) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.ui.creation.section.PmoBasedSectionFactory.createAndBindSection(PmoBasedSectionFactory.java:82) ~[linkki-core-vaadin23-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.ui.creation.section.PmoBasedSectionFactory.createSection(PmoBasedSectionFactory.java:55) ~[linkki-core-vaadin23-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.vaadin.component.page.AbstractPage.addSection(AbstractPage.java:106) ~[linkki-core-vaadin23-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at de.ts.ns.tg.Test.view.TestPage.createContent(TestPage.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.linkki.core.vaadin.component.page.AbstractPage.init(AbstractPage.java:89) ~[linkki-core-vaadin23-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at de.ts.ns.tg.Test.view.TestView.<init>(TestView.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.linkki.core.binding.LinkkiBindingException: Cannot read value from object: de.ts.ns.tg.Test.view.HelloPmo@61527686, property: name in org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.ReadMethod.readValueWithExceptionHandling(ReadMethod.java:75)
    at org.linkki.core.binding.ElementBinding$AspectUpdaters.updateUI(ElementBinding.java:169) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.ElementBinding.updateFromPmo(ElementBinding.java:78) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    ... 126 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.linkki.core.binding.LinkkiBindingException: Cannot read value from object: de.ts.ns.tg.Test.view.HelloPmo@61527686, property: name
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.ReadMethod.readValueWithExceptionHandling(ReadMethod.java:75) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.ReadMethod.readValue(ReadMethod.java:60) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.PropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(PropertyAccessor.java:57) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.pull(ReflectionPropertyDispatcher.java:103) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.pull(AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.java:65) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.staticvalue.StaticValueDispatcher.pull(StaticValueDispatcher.java:58) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.pull(AbstractPropertyDispatcherDecorator.java:65) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.behavior.BehaviorDependentDispatcher.pull(BehaviorDependentDispatcher.java:104) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.ui.aspects.ValueAspectDefinition.lambda$createUiUpdater$0(ValueAspectDefinition.java:127) ~[linkki-core-vaadin23-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.util.handler.Handler.lambda$andThen$1(Handler.java:47) ~[linkki-utils-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.util.handler.Handler.lambda$andThen$1(Handler.java:46) ~[linkki-utils-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.util.handler.Handler.lambda$andThen$1(Handler.java:47) ~[linkki-utils-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.util.handler.Handler.lambda$andThen$1(Handler.java:46) ~[linkki-utils-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.ElementBinding$AspectUpdaters.updateUI(ElementBinding.java:165) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    ... 127 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't create CallSite for MethodHandle(HelloPmo)String
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.ReadMethod.getCallSite(ReadMethod.java:103) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.AbstractMethod.getMethodAs(AbstractMethod.java:95) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.ReadMethod.getter(ReadMethod.java:82) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.ReadMethod.readValueWithExceptionHandling(ReadMethod.java:71) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    ... 140 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Invalid caller: de.ts.ns.tg.Test.view.HelloPmo
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.<init>(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:123) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.<init>(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:175) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:336) ~[na:na]
    at org.linkki.core.binding.dispatcher.reflection.accessor.ReadMethod.getCallSite(ReadMethod.java:96) ~[linkki-core-2.1.2.jar:na]
    ... 143 common frames omitted
```

It looks like it is not possible for linkki to access the getName()-Method. I found [LambdaMetafactory to access class on a different ClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441650/lambdametafactory-to-access-class-on-a-different-classloader) but have no clue if there is a way to fix it on my side.

Comment: Which Java version do you use, @thorsten?

Comment: I use Java17 17.0.1

Answer (score 2):

In fact it is a class loading problem with spring-boot-devtools (using RestartClassLoader) and java 17. There is no problem when either using java 11 or disable spring-boot-devtools for exaple by removing the dependency from pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the Java-Version. With Java11 there is no problem and the newly generated code works fine. I filed a bug.